# React router and express

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router

Recently I am using MERN stack as my web development stack. However, I could not figure out that how to handle client side rendering and server side rendering.

I have a URL like: http://localhost:3000/addItem and I route this URL using react router. It works well. But when I input the URL in the browser and hit the enter button, 404 paged showed.

I understand the reason is I did not set up the get request in express.js
However, my question is should I just leave it in this way? or I should also implement the get request in express as well?

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html file you might have included the js bundle in the script tag file like below.
src="js/bundle.min.js"

It should be 
**src="/js/bundle.min.js"**

You need the '/' to make it absolute path. else it'll try to find the JS file in the relative path of the URL you entered.